# Magento bundle products special price for child item only

Tags: magento, bundle, product

**Background**

I am trying to create a possibility on the webshop to create packs of products. A pack is for instance a product (let's say a digital camera) and multiple accessories (extra charger, memory cards, ...). The point is to push the customer into buying the product together with accessories by giving a discount if you buy all these products together.

**What I've done so far**

I've created a bundled product in magento where each product is a bundle option. This way I managed to display the pack correctly and I'm able to set a special price for the pack as a whole.

**Where I need help with**

For this pack I should be able to set the price of the children (the option products) for each option. Currently the price can only be set for the whole package and I require it to be changed like a special price. Basically you would have a special price only if it is in a bundle product and the price should be set specifically for the bundle.

By default, a quantity can be set with bundled options, so I guess this can be extended to something where I can set a price. Can anyone point me in the right direction of give me some code examples of how this can be done?

In case this should be necessary, we are running Magento Enterprise 1.9.1.1.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody came with a solution I will answer my own question... I actually was on the right track and just had to change the price type to "fixed" when you create a new bundled product. That way, the price can be set per item individually which was what I wanted.

The rest was just a simple matter of coding the bundle products to display nicely, f.e. as simple items separated by a "plus" sign or something like that. I also removed the unit prices so only the bundle price is visible, but the prices are still set correctly. Also the base price (bundle price) should be set to 0.

And that was it, not much coding, but more bad luck I started with "dynamic" pricetype instead of "fixed".